# How to find out the name of an item having the wikidata code Q89 =>(apple)

Tags: python, wikipedia, wikidata, pywikibot

How to find out the name of an item having the wikidata code  Q89 (apple) , for properties I made a dictionary,but for item code I can't find anithing , I am using pywikibot for other operations , it is there any function do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Wikidata API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php) to get a JSON representation of the entity, including its labels:
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&ids=Q89&format=json&props=labels

Or, from the command-line, you can use a tool such as (the one I wrote ;)) [Wikidata CLI](https://github.com/maxlath/wikidata-cli#wd-label): `wd label Q89`